# “Waited for * || true but it wasn't there ” apt error

Tags: installation, apt, updates, dpkg, error-handling

I have run into an error with apt that seems to occur every time I update. The error outputs every time I try to install something via apt. Here is the output;

```
E: Waited for /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true but it wasn't there     
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true
```

running version 12.04.3

Answer (score 0):

This means that you somehow screwed up your configuration scripts, the reason why this is happening is because DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true";}; doesn't exist in your scripts so you may have to create it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs {"/usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt ||       true";};' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf"
```

Now retry your install.

*thanks to Braiam for this answer*